# react router 6 custom path match test

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm writing React app inside a non-React app, and I have no control over the relative route of my app (for example could be foo.com/bar/my-react-app). So the requirement is matching routes against the end of the URL(this is safe because the React js files are being loaded only when the user navigates to the route of my react app, so no collisions).

based on my check, the path check of `Route` in router-router v6 is not flexible or configurable, but in my case i need a custom check, with the end of the string's route.

for example one of the next checks would do the trick:

prefix is not possible

```
<Route path="*/admin" element={<UserApp />} />
```

custom function is not possible either

```
<Route path={(route)=>route.endsWith("admin")} element={<UserApp />} />
```

I started looking at the source code and they using primarily `<string>.startsWith` and do not expose many customization options, so I came here to you experts before wasting a few hours trying to recreate the path match behavior with the low level components.

by the way `BrowserRouter` `basename` attribute does not help me either because i have no guarantee of the URL+route my app would be installed, so the check must rely on the end of the location string.

so, there is an easy way to make a route with custom path validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who encountered in my case - v6 is much less flexible as it does not support [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) [path matches](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) nor [custom render method](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for `Route`... so `Route path="*/admin"` would just work out of the box in v5

they should have left it in the API in my opinion. migrating back to v5 was trivial for my case and solved the issue.

Comment: Lack of regex breaks my auth library, so, huge pain for us too.